# Invoke Combobox from PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html, json, combobox

I have a PHP file that parses a JSON list and feeds it to a combobox:

```
<?php
    $jsonData = '{"marco":"marco@test.it", "giovanni":"giovanni@mail.it"}';
    $json = json_decode($jsonData, true);

    $opts = '';
    foreach($json as $name => $email)
    {
    $opts .= '<option value="'.$email.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }

    echo ' <select name="Team1">'.$opts.'</select> <br> ';
    echo ' <select name="Team2">'.$opts.'</select> <br>';

?>
```

I'm trying to include it in an HTML page, so that when it loads it will show the combobox:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Invio Mail </title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <form name="mail" action="mailer.php" method="post">
            <p>
            <center><b> Invio mail </b> 
            <br>
            <br>
            <? include("combobox.php") ?><br>
            Messaggio: <input type="text" name="name" rows="5" required><br>
            <br>
            <center><input type="submit" value=" Invia "></center><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I can't manage to make them appear!

I don't need a real time update, it's enough that the list is updated when the page is created.

Also, I can't manage to read the associated value from the combobox.

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump` the `$json` variable after doing the decode to make sure it actually decoded? Might be tripping on JSON syntax.

Comment: be careful with short open tags (<? and ?>) because it can be disabled in your server configuration. If so, the embedded code won't even appear

Comment: is your `HTML page` a `.php` file or `.html`? won't work if it is a `.html`

Comment: @cillosis yeas, the variable is correctly decoded, if i open the php file it works flawless, as you can see here: http://www.titadota2.eu/combobox.php

Comment: @Sean the first snippet is from a php page: http://www.titadota2.eu/combobox.php but the second is from an html page

Comment: @Jhyrachy Then take the suggestion from Cr3aHal0 and avoid the short open tags. Its possible you have them disabled in your config and that is why it isn't processing it. Also take the suggestions of Sean and make sure that page with the HTML has a .php extension. Unless your web server is configured to parse .html files for PHP (doubtful) then its not even looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the HTML page has the `.php` extension instead of `.html` and check if your webserver supports `short open tag` for php.

Edit:
You can check the `phpinfo()` if `short_open_tag` has the value `on`.

Edit 2:
You can access the selected value in your `mailer.php` with `$_POST['Team1']` and `$_POST['Team2']`

Comment: Ok, now it works, thanks!

One more question, how can i get the value from the selected item of the combobox?

Comment: Do you want to get the selected value after submitting the form or with javascript after selecting a value?

Comment: if i select "marco" when i submit the form i would like to send to mailer.php the email associated

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
<? include("combobox.php") ?>
```

to

```
<?php include("combobox.php") ?>
```

So, html code will be:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Invio Mail </title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <form name="mail" action="mailer.php" method="post">
            <p>
            <center><b> Invio mail </b> 
            <br>
            <br>
            <?php include("combobox.php") ?><br>
            Messaggio: <input type="text" name="name" rows="5" required><br>
            <br>
            <center><input type="submit" value=" Invia "></center><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```